# Multiply contacts' name On update (ContentProviderOperation)

Tags: java, android, list, contacts, android-contentresolver

A very strange porblem. I'm tring to update contacts name by this rule:
- if a contact's name start with "bit" + space ("bit ") so -> update the contact's name to name.substring(4, name.length()), and that means that the contact name will update without the "bit ".

when I use name.substring from number that lower them 4 (I think until the space in contact's name) its working perfectly. When I use from the 4 character onwards the contact's name multiply. For exmaple, when i use name = name.substring(4, name.length()) while name equal to "bit Lili" its update to:
Lili Lili.

```
 private void updateContact(String name) {
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    String where = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ?";
    String[] params = new String[] {name};
    Cursor phoneCur = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,null,where,params,null);
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    if ((null == phoneCur)) {//createContact(name, phone);
        Toast.makeText(this, "no contact with this name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;} else {ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(android.provider.ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(where, params)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name.substring(4,name.length()))
                .build());
    }

    phoneCur.close();

    try {cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);} 
    catch (RemoteException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (OperationApplicationException e) {e.printStackTrace();}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not a certain answer but it suppose to work the issue you have is with the

```
.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME //This specific part has a problem with the new update function
            ,name.substring(4,name.length()))
```

So my fix proposal is to change it to family name and given name change these as you need based on your question you want to remove the given name so it's a fix for that

```
 public static boolean updateContactName(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String name) {
    if (name.length() < 4) return true;
    String givenNameKey = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME;
    String familyNameKey = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME;
    String changedName = name.substring(4, name.length());
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();

    String where = ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ?";
    String[] params = new String[]{name};

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(where, params)
            .withValue(givenNameKey, changedName)
            .withValue(familyNameKey, "")
            .build());
    try {
        context.getContentResolver()
                .applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```